# How to get the remaining size on C: with ansible?

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-facts

I need to get the remaining size of the C: partition, and I have trooble to do it with the win_disk_fact module.
The final objective is to check if the remaining size is less than 4GB before processing a software installation but for now I'm just trying to print the value with a debug.

I use the win_disk_facts module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_disk_facts_module.html) and I can display the right value with

```
- debug:
    var: ansible_facts.disks[0].partitions[1].volumes[0].size_remaining
```

But depending on where this role will be used, the C: partition might not be on the first disk, partition 1, volume 0, It might be somewhere else I have no ideas of that (I'm developping a generic role that will be largelly used by other people)

I tried to use a jinja filter, but when I display the var it returns empty:

```
var: 
  disk_C: '{{ ansible_facts.disks|selectattr("drive_letter", "C") }}'

  - debug:
      var: disk_C
```

---

There is also something I don't get, if I try to display the size in :

```
- debug:
    var: ansible_facts.disks[0].partitions[1].volumes[0].size_remaining
```

The result is :

```
ok: [lab-win-01] => {
    "ansible_facts.disks[0].partitions[1].volumes[0].size_remaining": "52275679232"
}
```

But if I try to store this value a new variable (to reuse it after in something else)

```
  vars:
    diskC: '{{ ansible_facts.disks[0].partitions[1].volumes[0].size_remaining }}'

- debug:
    var: diskC
```

Then the result is :

```
ok: [lab-bs-win-01] => {
    "diskC": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Please, could someone enlight me on these two questions?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
 # Check space free of directory C:
  - name: 'Check free space in C:'
    win_shell: 'Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object Free | ft -HideTableHeaders'
    register: freespace

  - block:
      - debug:
          msg: "Directory C: there is not free space enough. End of play."
      - meta: end_play
    when: freespace == '1500000000'

  - debug:
      msg: "Directory C: has free space enough. Continue play."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
when: freespace == '1500000000'
```

The compare statement above is not able to compare the integer well. So, below is the updated codes.

```
---
- name: Check disk space C for patch
  hosts: '{{ host }}'
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: 'Check free space in C:'
    win_shell: 'Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object Free | ft -HideTableHeaders'
    register: freespace

  - block:
      - debug:
          msg: "Directory C: there is not free space enough. End of play. Free space is, {{ freespace.stdout_lines[1] }} "
      - meta: end_play
    when: freespace.stdout_lines[1]|int < 1500000000

  - debug:
      msg: "Directory C: has free space enough. Continue play."
```